# Dijkstra's algorithm simulation

Tags: java, algorithm, compiler-errors

I'm working on a implementation of Dijkstra's shortest path algorithm to simulate how multicast routing works but I'm getting an error on my simulation class and would appreciate if anyone could help me.

Simulation class

```
public class simulation
{
    private List<Vertex> nodes;
    private List<Edge> edges;
    public void testExcute()
    {
        nodes = new ArrayList<Vertex>();
        edges = new ArrayList<Edge>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
        {
            Vertex location = new Vertex("Node_" + i, "Node_" + i);
            nodes.add(location);
        }
    }
    addLink("Edge_0", 0, 1, ((int)Math.random()*101));
    addLink("Edge_1", 0, 2, ((int)Math.random()*101));
    addLink("Edge_2", 0, 4, ((int)Math.random()*101));
    addLink("Edge_3", 2, 6, ((int)Math.random()*101));
    addLink("Edge_4", 2, 7, ((int)Math.random()*101));
    addLink("Edge_5", 3, 7, ((int)Math.random()*101));
    addLink("Edge_6", 5, 8, ((int)Math.random()*101));
    addLink("Edge_7", 8, 9, ((int)Math.random()*101));
    addLink("Edge_8", 7, 9, ((int)Math.random()*101));
    addLink("Edge_9", 4, 9, ((int)Math.random()*101));
    addLink("Edge_10", 9,10,((int)Math.random()*101));
    addLink("Edge_11", 1,10,((int)Math.random()*101));

    // Lets check from location Loc_1 to Loc_10
    Graph graph = new Graph(nodes, edges);
    DijkstraAlgorithm dijkstra = new DijkstraAlgorithm(graph);
    dijkstra.execute(nodes.get(0));
    LinkedList<Vertex> path = dijkstra.getPath(nodes.get(10));

    for (Vertex vertex : path) 
    {
      System.out.println(vertex);
    }
    public void addLink(String laneId, int outcomingPortLabel, int incomingPortLabel,int cost)
    {
    Edge link = new Edge(laneId,nodes.get(outcomingPortLabel), nodes.get(incomingPortLabel), cost);
    edges.add(link);
    }
}
```

Edge class

```
package multicastroutingproject;
public class Edge  
{
    private final String id; 
    private final Vertex source;
    private final Vertex destination;
    private final int weight; 

    public Edge(String id, Vertex source, Vertex destination, int weight) 
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.source = source;
        this.destination = destination;
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public String getId() 
    {
        return id;
    }
    public Vertex getDestination() 
    {
        return destination;
    }
    public Vertex getSource() 
    {
        return source;
    }
    public int getWeight() 
    {
        return weight;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
    return source + " " + destination;
    }
}
```

Graph class

```
package multicastroutingproject;
import java.util.List;
public class Graph 
{
    private final List<Vertex> vertexes;
    private final List<Edge> edges;
    public Graph(List<Vertex> vertexes, List<Edge> edges) 
    {
        this.vertexes = vertexes;
        this.edges = edges;
    }
    public List<Vertex> getVertexes() 
    {
        return vertexes;
    }
    public List<Edge> getEdges() 
    {
        return edges;
    }
}
```

Vertex class

```
package multicastroutingproject;
public class Vertex 
{
    final private String id;
    final private String name;
    public Vertex(String id, String name) 
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() 
    {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) 
    {
        if (this == obj)
          return true;
        if (obj == null)
          return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
          return false;
        Vertex other = (Vertex) obj;
        if (id == null) {
            if (other.id != null)
                return false;
        } 
        else if (!id.equals(other.id))
            return false;
    return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return name;
    }
}
```

and finally Dijkstra's class

```
package multicastroutingproject;
import java.util.*;
public class DijkstraAlgorithm 
{
  private final List<Vertex> nodes;
  private final List<Edge> edges;
  private Set<Vertex> settledNodes;
  private Set<Vertex> unSettledNodes;
  private Map<Vertex, Vertex> predecessors;
  private Map<Vertex, Integer> distance;
  public DijkstraAlgorithm(Graph graph) 
  {
    // create a copy of the array so that we can operate on this array
    this.nodes = new ArrayList<>(graph.getVertexes());
    this.edges = new ArrayList<>(graph.getEdges());
  }
  public void execute(Vertex source) 
  {
    settledNodes = new HashSet<Vertex>();
    unSettledNodes = new HashSet<Vertex>();
    distance = new HashMap<Vertex, Integer>();
    predecessors = new HashMap<Vertex, Vertex>();
    distance.put(source, 0);
    unSettledNodes.add(source);
    while (unSettledNodes.size() > 0) 
    {
      Vertex node = getMinimum(unSettledNodes);
      settledNodes.add(node);
      unSettledNodes.remove(node);
      findMinimalDistances(node);
    }
  }
  private void findMinimalDistances(Vertex node)
  {
    List<Vertex> adjacentNodes = getNeighbors(node);
    for (Vertex target : adjacentNodes)
    {
      if (getShortestDistance(target) > getShortestDistance(node)
          + getDistance(node, target)) 
      {
        distance.put(target, getShortestDistance(node)
            + getDistance(node, target));
        predecessors.put(target, node);
        unSettledNodes.add(target);
      }
    }
  }
  private int getDistance(Vertex node, Vertex target) 
  {
    for (Edge edge : edges) 
    {
      if (edge.getSource().equals(node)
          && edge.getDestination().equals(target)) 
      {
        return edge.getWeight();
      }
    }
    throw new RuntimeException("Should not happen");
  }
  private List<Vertex> getNeighbors(Vertex node) 
  {
    List<Vertex> neighbors = new ArrayList<Vertex>();
    for (Edge edge : edges) 
    {
      if (edge.getSource().equals(node)
          && !isSettled(edge.getDestination())) 
      {
        neighbors.add(edge.getDestination());
      }
    }
    return neighbors;
  }
  private Vertex getMinimum(Set<Vertex> vertexes) 
  {
    Vertex minimum = null;
    for (Vertex vertex : vertexes) 
    {
      if (minimum == null) 
      {
        minimum = vertex;
      } 
      else 
      {
        if (getShortestDistance(vertex) < getShortestDistance(minimum)) 
        {
          minimum = vertex;
        }
      }
    }
    return minimum;
  }
  private boolean isSettled(Vertex vertex) 
  {
    return settledNodes.contains(vertex);
  }
  private int getShortestDistance(Vertex destination) 
  {
    Integer d = distance.get(destination);
    if (d == null) 
    {
    return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }
    else
    {
      return d;
    }
}
public LinkedList<Vertex> getPath(Vertex target) 
{
  LinkedList<Vertex> path = new LinkedList<Vertex>();
  Vertex step = target;
  // check if a path exists
  if (predecessors.get(step) == null) 
  {
    return null;
  }
  path.add(step);
  while (predecessors.get(step) != null) 
  {
    step = predecessors.get(step);
    path.add(step);
  }
  // Put it into the correct order
  Collections.reverse(path);
  return path;
  }
}
```

When I try

`addLink("Edge_9", 4, 9, ((int)Math.random()*101));`

It gives me the following warning/error: "Invalid method declaration;missing return type", and it suggests that I rename addLink to simulation, which makes no sense.

The other warning/error I'm getting on the lines

```
DijkstraAlgorithm dijkstra = new DijkstraAlgorithm(graph);
dijkstra.execute(nodes.get(0));
```

it says that package dijkstra does not exist, although I clearly instantiate the object on the obove line.

And lastly,

```
LinkedList<Vertex> path = dijkstra.getPath(nodes.get(10));

for (Vertex vertex : path) 
{
  System.out.println(vertex);
}
```

This time it says "Illegal start of type", and it suggests that I create a "path" class in my package, but again that makes no sense as I instantiate path right above the for each loop.

I'm sorry for the long post, but does anyone know why I'm getting these errors
?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several issues there, but the most glaring is that your calls to `addLink()` are in the middle of the class body, rather than in a method. The compiler expects a method declaration there and don't quite know what to do with those calls.
It seems that you are missing a `main()`. You should review some Java syntax.

Comment: Right on! Thanks a bunch. I've programming in ruby and python a lot so my java is a little rusty. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: It happens to all who switch from one language to another.. I often use the right syntax in the wrong place myself.